# Selecting value in drop down list in Chrome recorder

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

I am trying to record a web workflow using the Chrome inbuilt recorder. When selecting a value from a drop down list, the following code is generated.

```
  "type": "click",
  "selectors": [
    [
      "aria/ Current Order - $1,023.34 total value"
    ],
    [
      "#fromOrder-menu-342-1"
    ]
  ],
```

The issue is that the total order value is included in the name of the drop-down list item, and this will never be the same for two different orders.

How can I change the selector (e.g. using wildcards, or just check for "starts with") to select the relevant value from the drop-down list (regardless of the ending text of the drop down list value description)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) by using `[attr^=value]` to grab an element based on the value it "starts with".

Assuming your desired element has an `aria-label` this works:

```
[aria-label^=" Current Order - "]
```